# Different results in PS shell and cmd.exe shell

Tags: powershell, cmd

This PowerShell code appears to have different results when it is run in the PS shell and the cmd.exe shell. These runs are on Windows 7 Professional.

```
PS C:\src\t\rd> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117

PS C:\src\t\rd> Get-Content .\prodlist.txt
123
456
789
345
221
PS C:\src\t\rd> Get-Content .\rd2.ps1
$orgfile = 'photo.main.jpg'
$prodfile = '.\prodlist.txt'
$replpat = '[^\.]*(.*)','$1'

Get-Content -PSPath $prodfile |
    ForEach-Object {
        $orgfile -replace $replpat | Out-Null
        Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "$_$($matches[1])" -WhatIf
    }
PS C:\src\t\rd> .\rd2.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\123.main.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\456.main.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\789.main.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\345.main.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\221.main.jpg".
```

This is the expected result.

However, running in a cmd.exe shell, it appears that the $matches variable is not retained to the next statement.

```
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117

17:12:41.25  C:\src\t\rd
C:>powershell -NoProfile -File .\rd2.ps1
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\src\t\rd\rd2.ps1:8 char:52
+ ...        Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "$_$($matches[1])" -What ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\123".
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\src\t\rd\rd2.ps1:8 char:52
+ ...        Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "$_$($matches[1])" -What ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\rd\photo.main.jpg Destination: C:\src\t\rd\456".
...
```

When I turn to a Windows 10 system, I have the same failing results in PowerShell using:

```
5.1.15063..674 PS shell
5.1.15063..674 cmd.exe shell
6.0.0.beta8 PS shell
```

Why is the $matches variable not valid in the next statement?
Why does this execute differently in the PS shell and cmd.exe shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain the behavior, but why take such a convoluted approach in the first place? Something like this would be clearer and more straightforward:

```
$suffix = $orgfile -replace '^[^.]*'
Get-Content $prodfile | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "${_}${suffix}" -WhatIf
}
```

Or like this if you want the replacement inside the loop with the search and replacement strings defined as variables:

```
$pattern     = '^[^.]*'
$replacement = ''

Get-Content $prodfile | ForEach-Object {
    $suffix = $orgfile -replace $pattern, $replacement
    Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "${_}${suffix}" -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: The intent was to make something more flexible. The replacement regex could produce anything that the destination could string together. I do agree that this is easier, and it probably works, but that is only in this simple case.

Comment: If you move the replacement into the loop and use variables for pattern and replacement it should be able to do everything that the code from your question does, but still in a more clear-cut way. See updated answer.

Comment: This does not answer the question of different behaviours, but I am going to accept it since it does present something that works, in a limited case at least.

Answer (score 0):

Like @AnsgarWiechers answer, this does not explain the different behaviour in different PowerShell environments. However, it does show something that works.

The core problem was using `-replace` rather than `-match`. Using `-match` will work, but Ansgar is correct that this work is best done once before processing content.

```
$orgfile = 'photo.main.jpg'
$prodfile = '.\prodlist.txt'
$replpat = '[^\.]*(.*)'

Get-Content -PSPath $prodfile |
    ForEach-Object {
        $orgfile -match $replpat | Out-Null
        Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "$_$($matches[1])" -WhatIf
    }
```